# 550 Can't remove directory: Permission denied

Tags: joomla, ftp

Its been a day I'm facing this problem. I don't know if its because of the hosting server or my configuration in joomla.

I'm trying to upload my joomla website to ftp using akeeba back up. First, I uploaded kickstart.php and the akeeba file for the website and it is successful.

Now, I did the installation using akeeba and the last part which shows a modal which displays a button "View your sites front end". Instead of going to the sites front end It downloads an index.php file.. Same when I type in http://mywesbite.com/

I check my ftp files and the files are complete. Now, I want to delete my files in ftp to restart my installation but I cannot delete them.

Error is.
Command:    RMD src
Response:   550 Can't remove directory: Permission denied
Command:    CWD /public_html/media/k2
Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/media/k2
Command:    RMD items
Response:   550 Can't remove directory: Permission denied
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (184,75,241,225,130,147)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   226-Options: -a -l
Response:   226 3 matches total

And when I even try to upload files from my computer to filezilla ftp..
Error is..

Status: Starting upload of C:\Documents and   Settings\jacqueline\Desktop\k2\assets\images\system\warning.png
Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/media/k2
Command:    MKD assets
Response:   550 Can't create directory: Permission denied
Command:    MKD /public_html/media/k2/assets/images/system
Response:   550 Can't create directory: No such file or directory
Command:    CWD /public_html/media/k2/assets/images/system
Response:   550 Can't change directory to /public_html/media/k2/assets/images/system:   No such file or directory
Command:    SIZE /public_html/media/k2/assets/images/system/video.png
Command:    CWD /public_html/media/k2/assets/images/system
Response:   550 Can't check for file existence
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (184,75,241,225,136,169)
Command:    STOR /public_html/media/k2/assets/images/system/video.png
Response:   553 Can't open that file: No such file or directory
Error:  Critical file transfer error
Response:   550 Can't change directory to /public_html/media/k2/assets/images/system:   No such file or directory

Can anyone help me with this. I've been dealing with this the entire day. Please HElp

Comment: Definitely a hosting configuration issue. I would talk to your hosting provider. Many have experience working with CMS.

Comment: What do you recommend me to do? Actually, my client just provided me ftp and cpanel details. I don't actually know the hosting provider. Too bad my client is on a vacation. I have to solve problem on my own.

Comment: As @DavidFritsch said, its a hsoting related issue. I dont think there will be anything you can do yourself to solve the issue, even with cPanel access. Wait till your client gets back and ask if it would be possible for hosting account details to talk to customer support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is pretty simple.
Your files are owned by the Apache daemon rather than FTP User permission.
In case, if you want to remove anything, you will need to do that by the Apache daemon permission.
There are several ways:
1/ Using cPanel, use File Manager from cPanel to remove it or do a chmod to 777 for the whole files (which allow guest ~ FTP user to full control the files)
2/ Install a Joomla File Manager extension such as MijoFTP to do a chmod to 777 for the whoel files, and then you can use FTP to remove any files.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

It is an easy solution if you use CuteFTP to remove an FTP Directory, including Hidden Files:

1. Open your CuteFTP program (you can install CuteFTP from the Web).
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or right click in the Main Window, then click on "Filter...".
3. Select the "Enable filtering" checkbox.
4. Select the "Enable server-side filtering" checkbox.
5. Type `-a` in the Remote filter field.
6. Click "OK"
7. Now You can delete this folders from FTP

[image: See this Screen shot]